# How to download tenor gifs via links using python

Tags: python, download, discord.py, gif, animated-gif

this is the method i am currently using

```
import requests
url = 'GIF-URL'
with open('downloaded.gif', 'wb') as f:
  f.write(requests.get(url).content)
```

This seems to be working fine with other links, but fails to do so with tenor gifs

and i just can't find any way to do it
i've tried some "tenor API" and it doesn't have endpoint to download through links
i've even tried using `urllib.request` and `wget.download()`

there is one python library `tenor-dl`, but it works in terminal and i want a code implementation

is there any way so that i can download a tenor GIF as well as other gifs using their URLs
Example URL: https://tenor.com/view/thumbs-up-double-thumbs-up-like-agreed-yup-gif-11663223

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use this link: https://media.tenor.com/7Ypq9_9najcAAAAS/thumbs-up-double-thumbs-up.gif

The link you put is to a webpage not the gif directly.

Comment: This command is actually for my discord bot and the `url` part will set by the bot itself, it xopies the gif from the chat in that format only, so is there any way that i can convert that webpage like to the actual .gif link?

Comment: These are tenor apis for python https://pypi.org/project/tenorpy/ and https://pypi.org/project/pytenor/